# "Is my calculation correct" is back again

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

The answers of [What should be done with "Is my calculation correct ?"-type questions?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1626/what-should-be-done-with-is-my-calculation-correct-type-questions) clear out that questions need not be deleted by the OP/Community.

Note: This is the Part-2 of the same issue but instead of editing it, I am starting this new thread so that the comments,answers and votes on the initial thread remain exclusive to "Deletion".

Some questions are answered in the comments and those questions are left unanswered.

Should they be answered in either of the following way?

1. The OP writes down an extended solution adding more details.
2. One of the members writes down an answer which covers greater ground.
3. Either the OP or a member adds a CW answer stating "Yes! You(I) are(am) correct! Lets party!" (*the last two words can be scrapped off ;)*

Is this required?
Should there be another way around this?

Comment: Yes I can see, that this has a little negative effect on the unanswered questions statistics. But if there are comments, stating the approach is correct I see no harm. If I see a question I usually encourage someone, to add it as an answer. I thought about to add a customise close reason "Yes, your calculation is correct." However I came to the conclusion, that nobody really benefits from that.

Comment: This is a great question, because I have run into a few cases where I have hemmed and hawed about deleting answers like #3, but they do actually answer the question asked.  I'd like to see how other people feel, though.